# Input textbox value is empty when submiting a web form in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to submit a webform by giving all the values in form input text boxes but when i call the submit button click from excel vba, one of the text boxes is becoming empty and throwing a validation error.

```
Sub Click_Btn()    
  Dim objForms As Object
  Dim vTxtInput As Variant
  'Set objIE = GetIEApp
  Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

  'Make sure an IE object was hooked
  If TypeName(objIE) = "Nothing" Then
    MsgBox "Could not hook Internet Explorer object", _
      vbCritical, "GetFields() Error"
    'GoTo Clean_Up
  End If
  objIE.Navigate "http://fly3.emirates.com/CAB/IBE/SearchAvailability.aspx"
  objIE.Visible = True

  Sleep 5000

  Set objForms = objIE.document.all

  'Choose one way Flights
  objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_onewaySearch").Click
  Sleep 1000

  objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_ddlTo-suggest").Value = "Sydney (SYD)"

  ' Departure
  objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_ddlFrom-suggest").Value = "Mumbai (BOM)"

  ' Departure Date
  objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_txtDepartDate").Value = "28 Sep 12"
  Sleep 1000

  objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_FS_FF").Click
End Sub
```

When i click the submit button for the form the `ctl00_c_CtWNW_ddlTo-suggest` text box is becoming empty and getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are not giving it enough time to validate the names of the `FROM` and `TO` Dropdowns (Yes - not Text Boxes)

Try this code (TRIED AND TESTED). Also I am using Late Binding with IE. Change as applicable in your code.

The `Sleep 5000` give the text in the drop downs enough time to validate itself with the list of the drop down.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub Click_Btn()
    Dim objForms As Object
    Dim vTxtInput As Variant
    Dim objIE As Object

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'Make sure an IE object was hooked
    If TypeName(objIE) = "Nothing" Then
        MsgBox "Could not hook Internet Explorer object", _
        vbCritical, "GetFields() Error"
        'GoTo Clean_Up
    End If

    objIE.Navigate "http://fly3.emirates.com/CAB/IBE/SearchAvailability.aspx"
    objIE.Visible = True

    Sleep 5000

    Set objForms = objIE.document.all

    '~~> Choose one way Flights
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_onewaySearch").Click

    '~~> From
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_ddlFrom-suggest").Focus
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_ddlFrom-suggest").Value _
    = "Mumbai (BOM)"
    Sleep 5000

    '~~> Departure Date
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_txtDepartDate").Focus
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_txtDepartDate").Value _
    = "28 Sep 12"
    Sleep 5000

    '~~> To
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_ddlTo-suggest").Focus
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_ddlTo-suggest").Value _
    = "Sydney (SYD)"
    Sleep 5000

    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_FS_FF").Focus
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_FS_FF").Click
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Here is `Way 2`, which is faster than `Way 1 (Above)` by `15 Seconds` as we are not using `Sleep 5000` for validating. This doesn't require you to validate the drop downs. What it does is it bypasses the `checkValidation();` javascript which gets executed in the ONCLICK event of the Submit Button.

**WAY 2**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub Click_Btn()
    Dim objForms As Object
    Dim vTxtInput As Variant
    Dim objIE As Object

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'Make sure an IE object was hooked
    If TypeName(objIE) = "Nothing" Then
        MsgBox "Could not hook Internet Explorer object", _
        vbCritical, "GetFields() Error"
        'GoTo Clean_Up
    End If

    objIE.Navigate "http://fly3.emirates.com/CAB/IBE/SearchAvailability.aspx"
    objIE.Visible = True

    Sleep 5000

    Set objForms = objIE.document.all

    'Choose one way Flights
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_onewaySearch").Click

    ' From
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_ddlFrom-suggest").Focus
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_ddlFrom-suggest").Value _
    = "Mumbai (BOM)"

    ' Departure Date
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_txtDepartDate").Focus
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_txtDepartDate").Value _
    = "28 Sep 12"

    ' To
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_ddlTo-suggest").Focus
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_CtWNW_ddlTo-suggest").Value _
    = "Sydney (SYD)"

    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_FS_FF").Focus
    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_FS_FF").onclick = _
    Replace(objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_FS_FF").onclick, _
    "checkValidation();", "true;")

    objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_c_FS_FF").Click
End Sub
```